# Please explain the following function

Tags: c++

I have come across a function definition starting as:

```
int operator*(vector &y)
{
  // body
}
```

After putting `*` just after operator and before opening brace of argument, what does this function mean?

Answer (score 7):

This is an `operator *` overload. The syntax you should use is `*(y)` while `y` is of type `vector`.

It allows you a reference like implementation, something similar to pointer reference in C. Of course the actual meaning depends on the body. e.g. you can return a reference to an internal element in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function overload for the `*` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Its function overloading which overload the de-reference operator `*`.

Answer (score 0):

It is either a dereferencing operator or a multiplication operator override. It is dereferencing if it is in a namespace and multiplication if it is inside a class. Since it has a body and no class scope I will also assume that it is a dereferencing.

Answer (score -2):

Actually its not a deferencing operator as in *ptr! Its actually an operator such as a multiplication operator. Here is a simple example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Int{
 int val;
 Int(const int val = 0) : val(val){}
 int operator*(const Int& number)const{
    return val * number.val;
 }
};

int main(){
  Int n(4), m(5);
  cout << n * m << endl; //use the operator*() implicitly
  cout << (n.operator*(m)) << endl; //use the operator* explicitly
}
```

To define a de-ferenceing operator, its prototype would be operator*(). Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) for more information. [Here](http://codepad.org/dzp6JJXp) is a live code to test.

Comment: Most overloaded operators can be defined as non-member functions, and unary * is no exception. http://ideone.com/sPixf If it is a member function, yes, it is binary *, but as shown unary * is more likely.

Comment: Oh wait yes you are right, didn't realize that it was a regular function.